# % Tuple in an array? python (not append tuple into array)

Tags: python

Say you have something like below:

```
x=10
l=11
list = ["%s bla","%s bla"%(x,l)]
print(list)
```

In this situation, you get this error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I'm assuming this is due to tuples being in an array.
Using `.format`, you'll get:

```
['{} bla', '11 bla']
```

Any solutions to my problem?

Comment: It's bad practice to define a list with name `list`

Comment: I don't actually do this, it was for the sake of example lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give each string its own variables:

```
x=10
l=11
list = ["%s bla" % x,"%s bla" % l]
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zip and a list comprehension to combine the values.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> L = 11
>>> lst = ["%s bla","%s bla"]
>>> [s % n for s, n in zip(lst, (x, L))]
['10 bla', '11 bla']
```

In your example, you were applying the formatting only to the second string, which has only one format specifier, but you were passing it two values, hence the error.

If you want to use `str.format`, just do it like this.

```
>>> lst2 = ["{} bla","{} bla"]
>>> [s.format(n) for s, n in zip(lst2, (x, L))]
['10 bla', '11 bla']
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of python(3.6 or later), You can also do:

```
x=10
l=11
l2 = [f"{x} bla",f"{l} bla"]
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
['10 bla', '11 bla']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your only assigning it to the last element another option is:

```
>>> x=10
>>> y=11
>>> l = ["%s bla","%s bla"]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0]%x[1],zip(l,[x,y])))
['10 bla', '11 bla']
```